# How do I add an element between all the other elements in an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a question, let's say I have this array:

```
$array = ["one", "two", "three", "four"];
```

And I want to add `"test"` between elements in the array, so it becomes like this:

```
$array = ["test", "one", "test", "two", "test", "three", "test", "four"];
```

My current way of doing it is by doing this:

```
$array = ["one", "two", "three", "four"];
$newArray = "test." . implode("test.", $array);
$newArray = explode(".", $newArray);
```

But I want a way that's cleaner, can somebody help me please?

Comment: In your example `$newArray` is a string not an array.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the line `$newArray = explode(".", $newArray);`, I edited the post.

Comment: Just a `foreach()` loop is about the simplest.

Comment: Define "cleaner". It's a straightforward solution, easy to understand and does the job. What are you looking to improve?

Comment: Oh yeah, a `foreach()` loop can do it, thanks.

Comment: To answer El_Vanja, I wanted a way that's in just 1 line, or maybe a function in PHP that does what I'm looking for.

Comment: For a one liner, you can always put your first function call directly into the other: `explode(".", "test.".implode(".test.", $array))`. Note that you have to implode with `.test.`, not `test.`.

Comment: That's true, although, I'm using the `foreach()` way, as it's also better just in case one of the elements had a dot in them.

Answer (score 1):

```
$array = [...]; // Defined in question
$newArray = [];
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $even = $key * 2;
    $odd = $even + 1;
    $newArray[$odd] = $value;
    $newArray[$even] = "test";

    // Or just reusing $key
    // $key *= 2;
    // $newArray[$key + 1] = $value;
    // $newArray[$key] = "test";
}
var_dump($newArray);
```